# Как дублировать запись, которая появляется меньше раз, чем это необходимо? Ошибка: "Подзапрос возвращает более одной записи"

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется БД с таблицами items, users и orders. Из таблиц users и items необходимо выбрать значения из стобца id (при условии, что логин в users – john, а категория в items – hats).

Для решения задания написал запрос.

```sql
INSERT INTO orders (user_id, item_id) VALUES
((SELECT id FROM users WHERE `login` = 'john'),
(SELECT id FROM items WHERE `category` = 'hats'))
```

Результат: ошибка #1242 - Подзапрос возвращает более одной записи. Понимаю, что john-ов для всех hat-ов не хватает, однако не могу придумать, как сделать так, чтобы id john-а каким-либо образом подставлялся сам, ведь логины уникальны.

Comment: Сама ошибка говорит о том, что один из селектов вернул более 1й записи. Смотрите, где у вас значения дублируются. Возможно стоит задать доп параметр для выборки или, быть может, переосмыслить сам insert(может можно id как то заранее вытащить или передать их откуда то)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . Понимаю, что john-ов для всех hat-ов не хватает, однако не могу придумать, как сделать так, чтобы id john-а каким-либо образом подставлялся сам, ведь логины уникальны.

Судя по описанию, у вас одна запись из юзеров, и N записей из `items` подходящих под условие. Ваша форма запроса INSERT предполагает вставку одной строки в таблицу. И поскольку в `items` у вас строк несколько, вы получаете соответствующую ошибку.

Чтобы вставить несколько строк в используйте форму запроса `INSERT ... SELECT`. А чтобы получить все подходящие строки, используйте JOIN.

```
 INSERT INTO order (user_id, item_id)
 SELECT u.id, i.id
 FROM users AS u 
 INNER JOIN items AS i ON (i.category = 'hats')
 WHERE u = 'John'
```

либо подзапрос

```
 INSERT ...
 SELECT 
      (select id from users where name = 'John')
    ,  i.id
 FROM items AS i
 WHERE category = 'hats'
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Натолкнули на нужные мысли.